# jqgrid hide row inside grid

Tags: jqgrid

How can I hide a row inside my grid? ( not delete it).

Comment: This is a suggestion, have you tried to handle a row alone, and see if has an method called something like setVisible ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not directly supported. You can use just `$("#"+rowid).hide()` to hide row with id="rowid", but some small things in the grid can be not so nice as before. For example it you use `rownumbers:true` the user will see that row numbers are not sequential. Moreover if you not use `height:'auto'` the table height will be not perfect. All the problem if needed you can fix manually.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#row_with_row_id","#mygrid").css({display:"none"});
```

Found here: [Trirand: Hide a row to certain conditions](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/hide-a-row-in-jqgrid)